# how to connect from my iphone to my localhost on my mac os

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, macos

i read many questions about it, but still i have problem.

when i was using localhost and correct **NSAppTransportSecurity** optinos from my simulator, everything was correct.

now i am debuging on my iphone. both the iphone and the mac are connecting to the same network.

i check the ip address of my mac

and i added it to **NSAppTransportSecurity** like this:

```
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>10.250.x.x</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

i am still getting error:

```
 App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
error = Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f904d300170 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://10.250.x.x:8080/IVRServer/api/registration/register, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://10.250.x.x:8080/IVRServer/api/registration/register, NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.}
```

should i add anything else to my plist?

please don't consider this quesitn duplicated because i am already using the correct settings in my plist, and it is working fine, but just when i change the server to not localhost it is not working

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to bypass this restriction, allow all loads:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

This should be feasible because presumably you are using your "local host" so there should not be any security concerns.

Comment: now i don't get that error, but i am getting error 404 not found, why?

Comment: @JackSong It's OK, I can "afford" it. Thanks for the note, though, really thoughtful of you.